# How to convert unitless line-height into percentage so that I can get correct value?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to convert unitless line-height into percentage but calculated value doesn't seem to be accurate.

Here's my web page `<body>` CSS:

```
body {
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:1.5;
}
```

and this is my `<h1>` CSS:

```
h1 {
    font-size:36px;
    line-height:1.2;
}
```

Now I am very curious to convert `line-height:1.2` of `<h1>` into percentage (%) unit.

So I did a little simple maths to first convert unitless 1.2 into pixels:

```
1.2 x 36px = 43.2px
```

Firefox Web Developer tools computed tab shows exactly the same above value.

If I change the CSS for `<h1>` to

```
line-height:43.2px;
```

*Please don't point out that I used decimal in pixels - I just wanted to put exact calculated value.

Obviously, I get the same result as when I used 1.2 line height.

Now I want to convert this pixel value to % value. The converted value comes out to be 270%.

```
(100 / 16) x 43.2 = 270%
```

And if I use this percentage value to `<h1>` then I get grotesque line spacing. However if I use 120%, then the output is same as when I used 1.2.

I don't understand why the result is weird if the calculation has been done accurately?

**When line-height is 1.2 or 43.2px or 120%**

[image]

**When line-height is 270%**

[image]

Comment: why you think it should be 270% it's indeed 120%

Comment: Yes you are right, but I don't know why I get 270%. Please see my updated question where I shown the formula. I know it is wrong but not sure what would be the correct method.

Comment: you are overcomplicating it, the percentage work the same way as uniteless. Using 1.2 means that you need 120%, as simple as that. There is a tiny difference explained in the duplicate

Comment: `1.2 x 43.2`, should be your calculation

Comment: Yes I understand but then why online converter (px to % etc.) gives me 270%?

Comment: `(100 / 16) x 43.2 = 270%` --> `(100 / 36) x 43.2 = 120%`

Comment: it should be (100 / font-size) * new-font-size

Comment: @Simplicius I think you are wrong. It yields 51.84.

Comment: @Sachin, I got the question wrong, thought he wanted to get the line-height for 43.2px, Temanis calculation is right in this case